How to build Unit Tests with Swift App with FirebaseApp.configure
I'm having issues getting Unit tests working with FirebaseApp.configure
When I comment out this the app is able to run the unit tests just fine
  FirebaseApp.configure()
  AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(YourSimpleAppCheckProviderFactory())

I tried adding a launch var to only configure when I'm not running my tests, commented out I was able to confirm that the var is correct. But somehow even without being called the FirebaseApp.configure() is causing it to not build.
It's failing with

CommandCodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
Undefined Symbols:
Linker command failied with exit code 1

Do you know how I can get this to build, I have linked all the necessary dep, if I hadn't it would have failed on import.
I don't want to mock db or anything, the tests have nothing to do with Firebase, I just want to build in test mode.
I tried this
        if !ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("unit_testing") {
            print("VAR NOT FOUND")
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            AppCheck.setAppCheckProviderFactory(YourSimpleAppCheckProviderFactory())
        }


but it's still failing to build

The solution ended up being to simply remove FirebaseFirestoreSwift from my Testing dependency.
So I ended up with FirebaseAppCheck and FirebaseFirestoreSwift in my main app and just FirebaseAppCheck in my UnitTest target.
This allowed me to build and run my tests. Since I'm not testing anything db related I don't need to mock.
